# Sending h5 file throught TCP ethernet

Tags: python, tcp, ethernet

My main objective is to send via ethernet TCP protokoll an h5 file. I used the h5py to load the file, i get the length of data, and I want to send from PC to RPi (PC is client RPi is host).

```
Host = "169.254.110.54"
Port = 7777
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((Host, Port))
print("Succeded connection!")

send_obj = h5py.File(model_path, 'r')
print(send_obj)
len = str(send_obj.__sizeof__())
print(len)

print(bytes(len, 'utf-8'))
i = 0

while True and i<1:
      try:
         s.send(bytes(len, 'utf-8'))
         print("Sending data!\n")
         ack = s.recv(1024)
         msg = ack.decode('utf-8')
         if(msg == "DRCV"):
             s.send(send_obj)
         print(msg)
         i= i+1
       except:
          pass
s.close()
print("Connection ended!")
```

Somebody any idea? I tried to convert my file into bytes or something else, whitout any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I couldn't manage to send this kind of file(h5) format over TCP connection, but if you save your model in .json you can easilly `open(model.json, 'r')` and spliting in desired datarame and sending `socket.send(bytes(modelString/1024),'utf-8')` (1024 bytes want to send in every package). I hope it helps everybody! :D